# How to Use ASM Library in Maven Project

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to use the ASM byte code engineering library in a maven project.  I put this in my pom

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

But my code fails to build, because no jar is present.  When I examine the contents of .m2 I see

```
ll ~/.m2/repository/asm/asm-parent/3.3.1/
total 40
drwxr-xr-x  6 david  staff   204 Oct 25 08:25 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 david  staff   170 Dec 24  2013 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 david  staff   156 Dec 18  2013 _maven.repositories
-rw-r--r--  1 david  staff   242 Oct 25 08:25 asm-parent-3.3.1.jar.lastUpdated
-rw-r--r--  1 david  staff  4332 Dec 18  2013 asm-parent-3.3.1.pom
-rw-r--r--  1 david  staff    40 Dec 18  2013 asm-parent-3.3.1.pom.sha1
```

And this:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project asm-test: 
Could not resolve dependencies for project com.example:asm-test:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: 
Could not find artifact asm:asm-parent:jar:3.3.1 in central 
(http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2), 
try downloading from http://mojo.codehaus.org/my-project -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Is there any reason you try to use the old version?

Comment: I think the problem is this: `<artifactId>asm-parent</artifactId>`. You should use the `<artifactId>asm</artifactId>` instead.

Comment: Ah, I see version 4 and 5 have a different groupId.  This worked better for me  `<dependency><groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId><artifactId>asm-all</artifactId><version>5.0.3</version</dependency>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

asm-parent dependencey type is pom,
try below

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm-parent</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
```

if you want to use asm only

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>asm</groupId>
    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

According to http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/asm/asm/3.3.1 The suggested usage is like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>asm</groupId>
    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

You were trying to use the parent project with defines only a pom.

BTW, there is a note:
Note: This artifact was moved to:

New Group   org.ow2.asm
New Artifact    asm

Answer (score 2):

Just an update for 2016, if you want to use full ASM library you can add this to your POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
    <artifactId>asm-all</artifactId>
    <version>5.1</version>
</dependency>
```